# Image preview feature not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a Javascript that is used for the preview of the image that needs to be uploaded. But the problem is it just works for the first chosen image and not for the rest of the images that needs to be uploaded. Here is the code for the image upload and preview.

```
<form id='uploadForm-<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>' action = '' enctype='multipart/form-data' method = 'POST' class="form<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>">
        <input type="file"  class="image<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>" name="img" onChange="readURL(this);" /><br/>
<input type="file"  class="image<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>" name="img" onChange="readURL(this);" /><br/>
<input type="file"  class="image<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>" name="img" onChange="readURL(this);" /><br/>
<input type="file"  class="image<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>" name="img" onChange="readURL(this);" /><br/>
<input type="file"  class="image<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>" name="img" onChange="readURL(this);" /><br/>
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" /><br/><br/>
        <input type='button' id = '<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>' class='uploadPicture<?php echo $imgCnt; ?> btn btn-primary' value = '上載'>
        <!-- <input type="button" value="上載" class="uploadPicture"  id="upload_btn<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>"/> -->
    </form>
```

And here is the Javascript for the *readURL* function that is called *onChange*

```
<script>

function readURL(input) {      
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            //$('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result).width(300).height(340);
             $(input).next('img').attr('src', e.target.result).width(300).height(340);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }

  }
</script>
```

Any clue how to achieve this feature.

Comment: hi, can you please check if the dataUrl provided by the image reader is starting with this "data:image/gif;base64,"?

Comment: @AllanChua I am sorry, I didnt get it. Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: can you please show a sample value for the e.target.result?

Comment: @AllanChua it gives the temporary value _phpE.tmp_